# Customising gesture on react native ios

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, swipe

On android one can add listener to Backhandler to detect hardware back action. So, if i create a screen and modify the content of the screen upon some action, then it is easy to go back to previous content with backhandler listener.

On ios, this is not possible to do with the swipe gesture.
React navigation does provide swipe gesture enable/disable to disable the action all together. But if i want to use the swipe gesture to update the content of the app, is it possible with react native/react navigation?

Or adding new screens with different content is the only and recommended option?

for example signing up on the app. 
On android what i do is create a single screen and modify its content with different sub components when user presses the next button and its easier to go back by listening to hardware press back. But on ios one can go back by swiping left to right. But using react navigation it goes back to previous screen and i find no way to listen to the gesture and go back to previous sub component instead of previous screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[React Native Swipe Gestures](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipe-gestures) use this library.

I hope it help you.

Comment: thanks it helped. i had to fork the repo and create a new package to remove deprecated methods. https://github.com/soumyamishra89/rn-swipe-gestures